# Get executed jobs form the scheduler in Quartz

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I want to retrieve scheduled but already executed jobs from the scheduler in Quartz. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Well, first you need to retrieve a list of all currently scheduled jobs:

```
Scheduler sched = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
List jobsList = sched.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
```

Then, it's a matter of iterating the list to retrieve the context for reach job. Each context has a getPreviousFireTime().

```
Iterator jobsIterator = jobsList.listIterator();   
List<JobExecutionContext> executedJobs = new List<JobExecutionContext>();  

while(jobsIterator.hasNext())
{
    JobExecutionContext context = (JobExecutionContext) jobsIterator.next();
    Date previous = context.getPreviousFireTime();
    if (previous == null) continue; //your job has not been executed yet

    executedJobs.Add(context); //there's your list!
}
```

The implementation may be slightly different depending on which quartz you use (java or .net) but the principle is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What is the jobList specified in the code? (The one you get the list iterator)

Comment: Here, I want to retrieve jobs which are completely executed (no longer running). If I can get all the jobs which are scheduled (currently executing + completely executed) from the scheduler, that is also fine.

Comment: @Chanikag I have updated the code segment to make it clearer. Hope it helps!

Comment: I want to get jobs which are completely executed and no longer executing. (next fire time is null) getCurrentlyExecutingJobs() method does not return those jobs.

Comment: @Chanikag it seems you need get a list of all jobs and then filter them, in that case you could use something like the GetJobs() method here: https://github.com/adometry/QuartzNetManager/blob/master/ClickForensics.Quartz.Manager/QuartzScheduler.cs

Comment: But GetJobGroupNames() also return nothing when all the tasks are completely executed.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property JobDetail.setDurability(true) - which instructs Quartz not to delete the Job when it becomes an "orphan" (when the Job not longer has a Trigger referencing it).